# Why I cannot see the graph drawn by draw_networkx_nodes?

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I am new to networkx and I am currently encountering some problem in seeing the figure that draw by `nx.draw_networkx_nodes`

The part of my code is shown as follows:

```
for key in disease_dic.keys(): # draw the hightlighted nodes
    try:
        nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,
                       nodelist=disease_dic[key],
                       node_size=500,
                       cmap = c)
        plt.axis('off')
        plt.savefig("gene-visualization.png") # save as png
        plt.show()
    except:
        print ("the node has some error but I want to ignore it first")
```

I couldn't find where the figure is, but I can get the messages that the figure is done shown as below (part of it)

```
<matplotlib.collections.PathCollection object at 0x7f500e0666d8>
(-0.7793968197316616, 1.12670270848741, -0.9354918928085955, 
1.0732247260915098)
<matplotlib.collections.PathCollection object at 0x7f500e066cc0>
(-0.7793968197316616, 1.12670270848741, -0.9354918928085955, 
1.0732247260915098)
 ...
 More of this
 ...
<matplotlib.collections.PathCollection object at 0x7f500e045978>
(-0.7793969427656775, 1.1267027173825332, -0.9354931999947296, 
1.073228508267067)
```

Comment: I think that a loop is not the best way to do this. If I'm reading this correctly, basically what you're telling it to do is to draw a brand new single-node figure for each key in your dictionary then save it to a file. Have you tried just calling the `draw_networkx_nodes` once with `nodelist` being a list of only the nodes you want to draw?

Comment: Two questions: 1) Can you show the form of `disease_dic`? (e.g. what does one of the values look like - is it a list of nodes?) 2) can you clarify the problem "I couldn't find where the figure is"? Do you mean that no window is produced? That there is a figure window, but it is empty? Or that you don't know where the `"gene-visualization.png"` file is written to?

Comment: The `nodelist = disease_dic[key]`  only draws the nodes that I want to draw. I think this part is working, but it doesn't pop up a window showing the figure.

Comment: 1) The form of disease_dic is a bit confusing, but `disease_dic[key]` is in a form of `[123,342,....]`.
2) Yeah, no window is poped up, and I couldn't find in the same directory with the python file. As I am running this on a remote server through `SSH`, it would bring more difficulty to find the figure.

Comment: ah it is quite possible the problem is with the remote server usage.  I'd suggest trying to test matplotlib independently of networkx to better isolate the problem.  If you don't use `ssh -X` or `ssh -Y` then the display won't be forwarded from the remote server to your machine.  In any case, the image should be written to the directory where you run this script from, on the remote server.  What is the output of `print(os.getcwd())` if you add that to the script? And can you not see the .png file in that directory?